# How to stop object from moving past last keyframe?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I have a simple animation showing a landing spacecraft. The problem is that after the object's last keyframe it still keeps moving--very slowly--like a breeze is pushing it across a layer of ice. How do I make it come to complete stop on all axes?

I think the issue came from my tweaking the Bezier curves in the graph editor, but no further tweaking stops the motion. Adding more keyframes downstream makes no difference. Ideally I'm looking for a command that will stop all motion (at frame 1100 in the example).  Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 3.6, Windows 11

[image: example]

Comment: try to change the last keyframe's interpolation to vector

Comment: You could also duplicate those keyframes and drag them to the end of your animation.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Duplicating the final keyframes and moving them to the end of the animation makes no difference (first thing I tried). Per your suggestion, I changed the Handle Type to Vector (Handle Type is the only place I found the Vector option) and that stopped the sliding on the X-Y axes, the only problem now is that the spacecraft is still moving very slowly on the Z axis. I think it's because the Z axis line on the graph editor is not _exactly_ horizontal, i.e., it has just a tiny slope; is there a way I can zero out this slope?

Comment: @WilburPost Select the last keyframe on the Z axis (with handles) then press `Z` `Y` `0` `Return` to scale vertically to 0, that should  probably help. Although if there is no more keyframe past that one, it should not slope down, even if you move the handle down a lot...

Comment: Thank you Gordon Brinkmann. Applying Z-Y-0 <Return> to the Z axis fixed it. I then noticed that the spacecraft was rocking gently along the X axis. Applying Z-Y-0 <Return> to that fixed the rocking, so now the spacecraft is showing zero movement.

Comment: Regarding slope, I find that I can select the last keyframe and use the handles in the Graph Editor to slope the line up or down way past (to infinity?) the last keyframe, so maybe I misunderstand. Thanks again! :)